# How are "immobilized" and "incapacitated" defined?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

As a Sentinel at launch I got two moves: Opportune Strike and Pommel Strike (these have since been removed from the game).  These can be used on immobilized (and slowed) and incapacitated targets respectively.  Initially I was able to use Pommel Strike on droids I had CC'd, but that no longer seems to be the case.  As well, one of them lights up when I'm holding an enemy still with Force Stasis, but I can't actually use it since the moment I click it the enemy is no longer held and it fails.  This is all pretty confusing.

When can I actually use these moves?  In other words, what's the difference between "immobilized" and "incapacitated" and how do I put enemies into those states?

Comment: Note that OS can also be triggered by Slow. I know that Guardians get a skill to immobilize targets after a Force Leap, meaning you can use either PS or OS if you are quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An incapacitated enemy is any enemy which is controlled (CC'd), stunned or knocked down.

Because champion enemies and above are not able to be controlled, Pommel Strike cannot be used against bosses in most operations / flashpoints.

The big deal here is that you can use Pommel Strike if someone *else* incapacitates the target, which makes it much easier to use for Knights/Warriors.

Comment: Sounds good ... how does immobilization differ?

Comment: One quibble: there are plenty of not-champion mobs in Ops/Flashpoints. In 50 HM FP's, I routinely use Eviscerate on my agent to burst down a strong inside stunlock or to nuke an incoming add.

Comment: As for how immobilization differ: immobilized targets cannot *move* but can still attack. It's what other games often refer to as 'rooted'. Most notably: Force Charge immobilizes your target momentarily, making it a natural combo with Pommel Strike on eligible targets.